# Replacing an exact string in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a string that looks like:

```
$String = "Size,Please Select,L Kids,XL Kids,S,M,L,XL"
```

I would like to replace ',XL' with ',XL (Out of Stock)' however i do not want it to replace 'XL Kids' too.

So i would need an outcome like:

```
$String_replaced ="Size,Please Select,L Kids,XL Kids,S,M,L,XL (Out Of Stock)"
```

I have tried using String replace but this will not work, i understand i will have to use preg replace but i am unsure how to do that.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lookaround based regex should work:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/(?<=^|,)\bXL\b(?=,|$)/', 'XL (Out of Stock)', $String);
```

This matches `XL` surrounded by word boundaries.

```
(?<=^|,) - Make sure XL is preceded by comma or at the start of line
(?=,|$) - Make sure XL is followed by comma or at the end of line
```

Comment: I have just tested the code and it seems to have solved my problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be:

```
preg_replace("/,XL(\,|$)/", ",XL (Out of Stock),", $String);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although preg_replace is perfectly acceptable, a quicker alternative if this is just a 'one-off' thing is to still use string replace:

```
$string = "Size,Please Select,L Kids,XL Kids,S,M,L,XL";
$newString = str_replace("L,XL","L,XL (Out Of Stock)",$string);
echo $newString;
```

This finds all ",XL" values that are preceded immediately by L.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a negative lookahead:

```
$String = "Size,Please Select,L Kids,XL Kids,S,M,L,XL";
$String_replaced  = preg_replace('/\bXL\b(?! Kids)/', 'XL (Out of Stock)', $String);
echo $String_replaced ,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
Size,Please Select,L Kids,XL Kids,S,M,L,XL (Out of Stock)
```